# I want to select two table and its column into single result

Tags: mysql

**I want to retrieve data from two table:**

**Table 1**

1. Row: User
   Column: name

**Table 2**

2. Row: userpoints
   Column: userid, points

**How to insert in below code to retrieve Name, userid, points?**

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))         
{
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];

    // search in all table columns

    // using concat mysql function

$query = "
    SELECT * 
      FROM `qa_userpoints` 
     WHERE CONCAT(`userid`, `points`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'
     LIMIT 1
    ";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);        
}
 else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `qa_userpoints` LIMIT 1";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: to do that, you need 1 column more in users and that is a ID column which links both tables

Comment: How to add in into single line? Please help